# form in codeigniter cannot submit in controller

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, form-submit

i have a problem regarding with form submission in my code. I have a form that would let the user to input his/her whole information profile and also in my form, i got dynamic input type boxes. In short i have a very large form in my html with JavaScript dynamic input type.

Now my problem is, i am printing the data submitted in my form from view to controller and it doesn't print anything or when i press submit button, the page only refreshes not submitting to the controller.

Here is my full view code:

```
<form name="Register" class="m-t" role="form" action="<?php echo site_url("user_login/register_user/reg_new") ?>" method="post">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="picture-container">
        <div class="picture">
            <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/LfmMVU71g-HKXTCP_QWlDOemmWg4Dn1rJjxeEsZKMNaQprgunDTtEuzmcwUBgupKQVTuP0vczT9bH32ywaF7h68mF-osUSBAeM6MxyhvJhG6HKZMTYjgEv3WkWCfLB7czfODidNQPdja99HMb4qhCY1uFS8X0OQOVGeuhdHy8ln7eyr-6MnkCcy64wl6S_S6ep9j7aJIIopZ9wxk7Iqm-gFjmBtg6KJVkBD0IA6BnS-XlIVpbqL5LYi62elCrbDgiaD6Oe8uluucbYeL1i9kgr4c1b_NBSNe6zFwj7vrju4Zdbax-GPHmiuirf2h86eKdRl7A5h8PXGrCDNIYMID-J7_KuHKqaM-I7W5yI00QDpG9x5q5xOQMgCy1bbu3St1paqt9KHrvNS_SCx-QJgBTOIWW6T0DHVlvV_9YF5UZpN7aV5a79xvN1Gdrc7spvSs82v6gta8AJHCgzNSWQw5QUR8EN_-cTPF6S-vifLa2KtRdRAV7q-CQvhMrbBCaEYY73bQcPZFd9XE7HIbHXwXYA=s200-no" class="picture-src" id="wizardPicturePreview" title="">
            <input type="file" name="employee-picture" id="wizard-picture" class="">
        </div>
         <h6 class="">Choose Picture</h6>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="register-body">
    <p>Personal Information</p>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="user_id" id="user_id" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="User ID" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="First Name" style="text-transform: capitalize;" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="middle_name" id="middle_name" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Middle Name" style="text-transform: capitalize;" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Last Name" style="text-transform: capitalize;" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Email Address" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="contact_no" id="contact_no" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Contact Number"  required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Password" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <label for="cvil_stat">Permanent address</label>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">    
            <label for="cvil_stat">Province</label>
            <br>
            <select class="form-group" name="province" id="province_id">
                <option> ----- Select Option ----- </option>
                <?php foreach($provinces as $province)
                echo '<option value='.$province->province_id.'>'.$province->province_name.'</option>'?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">    
            <label for="gender">City</label>
            <br>
            <select class="form-group" name="city" id="city_id">
                <option> ----- Select Option ----- </option>                
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="street_name" id="street_name" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="House no. / Street name" required>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="philhealth_no" id="philhealth_no" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Philhealth Number" style="text-transform: capitalize;" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="pagibig_no" id="pagibig_no" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Pag-ibig Number"  required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="tin_no" id="tin_no" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="TIN Number" style="text-transform: capitalize;" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">    
            <input type="text" name="dependentnumber" id="dependentnumber" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Number of Dependent Child" style="text-transform: capitalize;" required>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="sss_no" id="sss_no" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="SSS Number"  required>
            </div>
        </div>        
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="place_ofb" id="place_ofb" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Place of Birth" style="text-transform: capitalize;" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">              
            <label for="gender">Birthday</label>
            <br>
            <select class="form-group" name="bday_month">
                <option>January</option>
                <option>February</option>
                <option>March</option>
                <option>April</option>
                <option>May</option>
                <option>June</option>
                <option>July</option>
                <option>August</option>
                <option>September</option>
                <option>October</option>
                <option>November</option>
                <option>December</option>
            </select>
            <select class="form-group" name="bday_day">
                <?php for($i=1;$i<32;$i++) {  ?>
                <option><?php echo $i ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
            <select class="form-group" name="bday_year">
                <?php $y = date('Y'); ?>
                <?php for($j=0;$j<120;$j++) { ?>
                <option><?php echo $y-$j ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">              
            <label for="gender">Religion</label>
            <br>
            <select class="form-group" name="religion">
                <option> ----- Select Option ----- </option>                
                 <?php foreach($religions as $religion)
                echo '<option value='.$religion->religion_id.'>'.$religion->religion_name.'</option>'?>
            </select>           
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">    
            <label for="cvil_stat">Civil Status</label>
            <br>
            <select class="form-group" name="civil_stat" id="civil_stat">
                <option> ----- Select Option ----- </option>
                <option value="Single">Single</option>
                <option value="Married">Married</option>
                <option value="Legally Separated">Legally Separated</option>
                <option value="Widowed">Widowed</option>                
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">    
            <label for="gender">Citizenship</label>
            <br>
            <select class="form-group" name="citizenship">
                <option> ----- Select Option ----- </option>
                 <?php foreach($citizenships as $citizenship)
                echo '<option value='.$citizenship->citizenship_id.'>'.$citizenship->citizenship_name.'</option>'?>
            </select>
        </div>

    </div>
    <p>Family Background</p>
    <div class="row" id="field_div">

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="fathers_name" id="fathers_name" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Father's Name" style="text-transform: capitalize;" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="fathers_occu" id="fathers_occu" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Occupation" style="text-transform: capitalize;" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="fdate_birth" id="fdate_birth" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Date of birth" style="text-transform: capitalize;" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="mothers_name" id="mothers_name" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Mother's Name" style="text-transform: capitalize;" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="mothers_occu" id="mothers_occu" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Occupation" style="text-transform: capitalize;" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="mdate_birth" id="mdate_birth" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Date of birth" style="text-transform: capitalize;" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p>Educational Background</p>
    <div class="control-btns">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="add_field_educ(event);">+</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="remove_field_educ(event);">-</button>
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper_educ">
        <div id="educ_div">
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>Work Experience</p>
    <div class="control-btns">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="add_field_work(event);">+</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="remove_field_work(event);">-</button>
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="wrapper_work">
        <div id="work_div">
        </div>
    </div>    

    <div class="register_footer">
        <button type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Clear</button>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Here is my controller code that i want to print my submitted code:

```
public function reg_new() {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', 'The %s is already taken.');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error"><li>','</li></div>');
        if ($this->form_validation->run('reg_config') == FALSE) {         
            $this->index();        
        } else {
            $register_data = array(
                'User_Id' => $this->input->post('user_id'),
                'First_Name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
                'Middle_Name' => $this->input->post('middle_name'),
                'Last_Name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
                'Email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'Contact_no' => $this->input->post('contact_no'),                
                'Password' => $this->bcrypt->hash_password($this->input->post('password')),
                'City_id' => $this->input->post('city'),
                'Street' => $this->input->post('street_name'),
                'Philhealth_num' => $this->input->post('philhealth_no'),
                'Pagibig_num' => $this->input->post('pagibig_no'),
                'Tin_num' => $this->input->post('tin_no'),
                'Dependent_children' => $this->input->post('dependentnumber'),
                'Sss_num' => $this->input->post('sss_no'),
                'Place_of_birth' => $this->input->post('place_ofb'),
                'Gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),               
                'Birthdate' => $this->input->post('bday_year') . "-" . date("m",strtotime($this->input->post('bday_month'))) . "-" . $this->input->post('bday_day'),
                'Religion' => $this->input->post('religion'),
                'Citizenship' => $this->input->post('citizenship'),
                'Civil_status' => $this->input->post('civil_stat'),

                'fathers_name' => $this->input->post('fathers_name'),
                'fathers_occupation' => $this->input->post('fathers_occu'),
                'father_bdate' => $this->input->post('fdate_birth'),
                'mothers_name' => $this->input->post('mothers_name'),
                'mothers_occupation' => $this->input->post('mothers_occu'),
                'mother_bdate' => $this->input->post('mdate_birth'),
                'User_Status' => $this->user_stat,
                'Delete_Status' => 0,
                'Position_Id' => 0,                    
            );

                if($this->input->post('civil_stat') == 'Married')  {
                    $spouse_data = array (
                            'Spouse_name' => $this->input->post('spouse_name'),
                            'Spouse_occupation' => $this->input->post('spouse_occu'),
                            'Spouse_bdate' => $this->input->post('spouse_dateofb'),
                    );
                }

                foreach ($this->input->post('educ_opt') as $educ) {
                    $count_educ = $count_educ++;
                }

                print_r($register_data);
                print_r($count_educ);
                print_r($spouse_data);

        }
    }
```

please take a look with my code why i cant submit it from controller.
thanks.

Comment: are you using `HMVC`? can you explain this `user_login/register_user/reg_new`?

Comment: @M.Hemant yes.. i was using HMVC

Comment: Did you check if you have access to reg_new, check console errors(javscript if you've). Create a basic form submit page and check if its is working. You can find then where the issue view or controller or paths.

Comment: @jones i already tried to submit with small form.. How do i trace if there is an error in my javascript ? .. i think my dynamic button has the problem. if i press adding input type, its like submitting ? how can i avoid it ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys.. i just figured it out, its because of my form validation that i thought it doesn't submit because it did not satisfy my form validation and for that i returned `$this->index();`